# Let $f$ be analytic in $\Bbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ and satisfy $f(x)=x^x$ for real $x>0$. Find $f(i)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in $\Bbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ and satisfy $f(x)=x^x$ for real $x>0$. Find $f(i)$.

What I did so far is: Define $g(z)=e^{z\log z}$ for with the principal branch. One can see that on the positive real line $g\equiv f$. If one takes another branch ($\arg z\ne 0$), for real $x$ one gets $g(x)=e^{x(\log x+i\arg x)}=x^x\cdot e^{ix\arg x}\ne x^x$, hence that is the only branch satisfying the conditions. Here is where I am stuck. Can I use the uniqueness theorem? I can't really understand how. I do know that if an open interval is an open set, taking $A=(0,\infty)$, $f$ and $g$ are identically equal, but how do I actually apply the theorem? I would appreciate any hint or remark.

Comment: The identity theorem for holomorphic functions does not require a nonempty open set on which the two functions coincide. It suffices that the set on which the functions coincide has an accumulation point in the domain.

Comment: Would $0$ satisfy such a point? Just to make sure the complex analysis carries no tougher condition for such a point?

Comment: @Meitar: No, because $0$ is not in the domain of $g$.

Comment: What point can I take, then, if there is any? I am quite confused in the matter.

Comment: @Meitar: How about $42$, or $5+\sqrt{223}$, or $1/\pi$?

Comment: It is clear now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by ${\rm Log}$ the principal value of $\log$. Then
$$f(z):=e^{z\,{\rm Log}(z)}$$
is analytic in the domain you specified, and coincides with $x^x$ when $z:=x>0$. One then has
$$f(i)=\exp\bigl(i\>{\rm Log}(i)\bigr)=\exp\left(i\cdot i{\pi\over2}\right)=e^{-\pi/2}\doteq0.2079\ .$$